# SMB from fedora 12 to windows network

Tags: samba, linux

I got Fedora 12 samab and samba client and permitted the same via the iptables.  For some reason, I cannot seem to browse my windows network.

What did I do wrong, and how can I achieve this.

Thanks
Jean

[edit] - I want to browse the windows workgroup
[edit] - Set the workgroup name, restarted the smb in the services, can browse network, but only my fedora 12 system is being shown

Comment: As a side note: Fedora 12 is quite outdated ago no longer supported. You should upgrade to a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following to allow Windows to talk to Fedora:

1. Allow samba services through system-config-firewall
2. Set the booleans I needed in system-config-selinux (filter for Samba)
3. Ran smbpasswd -a {nameofuser} as root for each user I wanted to add, setting a password. Note nameofuser doesn't need to be a UNIX user, and you can set up maps in /etc/samba/smbusers.
4. Uncommented the parts of smb.conf that make samba a WINS server i.e. `wins support = yes`
5. On windows I set it to use the Samba WINS server via the IP my Linux box (well, VM) had.

That's roughly it (done at work, not home). I haven't figured out how to go the other way yet; I suspect for that you need to set Windows up as the Wins server...?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if no firewall is turned on on the windows side.
Windows Firewall does block this if the network type is set to Pyblic (on Vista/7). Yous hould set the network type to "home" for best performance with this kind of stuff. But make sure you turn it off on hotspots and other public places.

Yvan

Comment: i want to browse the windows workgroup

Comment: ofcourse, but aren't there any firewalls installed on the Windows side? Every version since XP has build in firewall, and the Vista/7 ones are quite restrictive when put into Public mode. So please check if you can browse the windows workgroup when all windows firewalls are turned off. It may take a while before all records of the computer names are updated...

Answer (score 0):

I had difficulty going the other way round as well.
Then I tried to use fixed ip instead of dhcp,
and it worked.